# How to subset a matrix by index

Tags: matlab

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
r_idx = [1 2]
c_idx = [1 2]
A(r_idx,c_idx) = [1 nan nan; nan 5 nan]
```

In other words, it should return the (1,1) and (2,2) elements of A and setting all other entries to be nan.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
r_idx = [1 2];
c_idx = [1 2];
B = nan(size(A));
B(sub2ind(size(A),r_idx,c_idx)) = A(sub2ind(size(A),r_idx,c_idx));
```

then, desired result is in B

Answer (score 2):

One approach with [`sparse`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) -

```
A(full(sparse(r_idx,c_idx,1,size(A,1),size(A,2)))==0) = nan
```

Or with [`setdiff`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) -

```
A(setdiff(1:numel(A),sub2ind(size(A),r_idx,c_idx))) = nan
```